# How to print the results of this code using recursion?

Tags: c, recursion

Here is source code of the C Program to Find the Sum of Series 1^2 + 2^2 + …. + n^2.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int number, i;
    int sum = 0;

    printf("Enter maximum values of series number: ");
    scanf("%d", &number);
    sum = (number * (number + 1) * (2 * number + 1 )) / 6;
    printf("Sum of the above given series : ");
    for (i = 1; i <= number; i++)
    {
        if (i != number)
            printf("%d^2 + ", i);
        else
            printf("%d^2 = %d ", i, sum);
    }
    return 0;
```

}

can someone please tell me how to get the same results of this code, but by using recursion

Comment: Do you have any examples that you could post that you have tried already? Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. People will be happy to help out if you have shown some effort in finding the solution yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is to introduce a new function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void printNumber(int, int, int);

int main()
{
    int number, i = 1;
    int sum = 0;

    printf("Enter maximum values of series number: ");
    scanf("%d", &number);
    sum = (number * (number + 1) * (2 * number + 1 )) / 6;
    printf("Sum of the above given series : ");

    printNumber(i, number, sum);
    return 0;
}

void printNumber(int i, int number, int sum){
    //if (i >= number) return; 
    //safe to remove above as i == number won't call the function again
    if (i != number){
        printf("%d^2 + ", i);
        printNumber(i + 1, number, sum);
    }
    else{
        printf("%d^2 = %d ", i, sum);
    }
}
```